# How to customize <span> in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I found this code on the internet and made some modifications for my need. I style first select list with css but i can't do the same for the second select list. I think it needs some js modifications but my js knowledge is not that good. How do i customize "slist2" like i did to "slist1" with css?

```html
<!-- The first select list -->
<style>
  #slist1 {
    height: 35px;
    border: 3px solid #0c3f6b;
    border-radius: 25px;
  }

  #scontent {
    color: #0c3f6b;
    font-size: 25px
  }
  
  #content {
    width: 290px;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px 15px;
  }
  
  #middle {
    width: 294px;
    /* Account for margins + border values */
    float: left;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    margin: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
  }
  
  #sidebar {
    width: 270px;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    float: left;
  }

</style>
<section id="content">
  PICK UP LOCATION
  <select name="slist1" div id=slist1 onchange="SList.getSelect('slist2', this.value);">
    <option>- - -</option>
    <option value="newyork">New York</option>
    <option value="miami">Miami</option>
  </select>
</section>
<!-- Tags for the seccond dropdown list, and for text-content -->
<section id="middle">
  <span id="slist2"></span>
</section>
<section id="sidebar">
  <div id="scontent"></div>
</section>


<script>
  <!--
  /* Script Double Select Dropdown List, from: coursesweb.net/javascript/ */
  var SList = new Object(); // JS object that stores data for options

  // HERE replace the value with the text you want to be displayed near Select
  var txtsl2 = 'DROP OFF LOCATION';

  /*
   Property with options for the Seccond select list
   The key in this object must be the same with the values of the options added in the first select
   The values in the array associated to each key represent options of the seccond select
  */
  SList.slist2 = {
    "newyork": ['San Diego', 'Portland','Ohio', 'San Francisco'],
    "miami": ['San Diego', 'Portland','Ohio', 'San Francisco'],
   
   };

  /*
   Property with text-content associated with the options of the 2nd select list
   The key in this object must be the same with the values (options) added in each Array in "slist2" above
   The values of each key represent the content displayed after the user selects an option in 2nd dropdown list
  */
  SList.scontent = { 
    
    "San Diego": '45€',
    "Portland": '60€',
    "Ohio": '35€',
    "San Francisco": '25€',
    
};

  /* From here no need to modify */

  // function to get the dropdown list, or content
  SList.getSelect = function(slist, option) {
      document.getElementById('scontent').innerHTML = ''; // empty option-content

      if (SList[slist][option]) {
        // if option from the last Select, add text-content, else, set dropdown list
        if (slist == 'scontent') document.getElementById('scontent').innerHTML = SList[slist][option];
        else if (slist == 'slist2') {
          var addata = '<option>- - -</option>';
          for (var i = 0; i < SList[slist][option].length; i++) {
            addata += '<option value="' + SList[slist][option][i] + '">' + SList[slist][option][i] + '</option>';
          }

          document.getElementById('slist2').innerHTML = txtsl2 + ' <select name="slist2" onchange="SList.getSelect(\'scontent\', this.value);">' + addata + '</select>';
        }
      } else if (slist == 'slist2') {
        // empty the tag for 2nd select list
        document.getElementById('slist2').innerHTML = '';
      }
    }
    -->

</script>
```

Comment: Sorry, what are you trying to achieve?  I only see one select list.  Just a wild guess but it seems you need to apply CSS to `#slist2`

Comment: Sorry, i had a mistake while pasting code here now i fix it.

Comment: You had a typo it works now, see my answer.

Comment: Sorry but this one is not my problem, i need to change and style "slist2".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<style>
[id^="slist"] {
    height: 35px;
    border: 3px solid #0c3f6b;
    border-radius: 25px;
}
</style>

 <select id="slist1"></select>
 <select id="slist2"></select>
 <select id="slist3"></select>
```

It makes your all elements with ID of value begins with "slist" styled the same.

Comment: When i did that it styles the row not the select list as you can see ; https://jsfiddle.net/ajolnir/b7Lypd63/

Comment: Ok I think I've just figured out what you want to do. Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/devrafalko/b7Lypd63/2/

Comment: OH! you made my day, thank you very very much, can you explain how you did it?

Comment: on the line:100 your javascript code creates a new (second) <select> element. I added an attribute class="myselect" there, also I added class="myselect" for the first <select> element (line 37). Now there are two <select> elements with class="myselect". Then I added a new rule (line 3) in <style> - .myselect{} which styles those both <select> elements.

Answer (score 1):

You would do it like this:

```
#slist1,
#slist2 {
    height: 35px;
    border: 3px solid #0c3f6b;
    border-radius: 25px;
}
```

or even better, like this:

```
.slist {
    height: 35px;
    border: 3px solid #0c3f6b;
    border-radius: 25px;
}
```

Then change your html to use a class (class="slist") instead of an ID.

It's also worth noting that they may not look EXACTLY alike since the span and select elements have very different default styles, AND style elements are a pain to style (in a cross-browser way, that is)

Comment: I did that but nothing changes, it uses "id" instead of "class" because id could be done something with script, when i try to change it with class script doesn't work:S

Comment: You'll have to change your script too.  Or leave your ID and your class.  Then you would just use the ID to hook into with your script, and the class for the css.  Classes are better for CSS because they're not as heavily specific as IDs, and it's easier to override later if you need to.